# Separately formatting date elements

Tags: date-time, date

I am trying to achieve the following look in the time format:

[image]

I have for now several issues,
First is that the month and year are not displayed at all,
I use `<?php the_date('D'); ?>` `<?php the_date('M'); ?>` `<?php the_date('Y'); ?>` for start and only the day is shown,

Second - Are there WP functions I can use to

- Get the month in 3 cap letters?
- Get only 2 last digits of year?

Or I have to use my own PHP functions for that?

Also, it must be hard-coded in the theme, because otherwise it will mess up the design.

**Update**
I used `<?php echo get_the_date('M'); ?>` and I got all the times, but isn't `the_date` meant exactly for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe all the info you need is in the [PHP Manual for Date/Time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Also, it is recommended that you use `get_the_date();` instead of `the_date();`

> **Get them month in 3 cap letters?**

`M` is the right format character that outputs a short textual representation of a month (3 chars). Why can't you use CSS to capitalize all the three letters? I mean, `text-transform: uppercase;` should do it.

> **Get only 2 last digits of year?**

Use the small `y`. It outputs two digit representation of a year.

**EDIT (to answer the updated question)**

The function reference for [`the_date();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) in codex has a **special note** that says:

> When there are multiple posts on a page published under the SAME DAY,
> `the_date()` only displays the date for the first post (that is, the
> first instance of `the_date()`). To repeat the date for posts published
> under the same day, you should use the Template Tag `the_time()` or
> `get_the_date()` (since 3.0) with a date-specific format string.